# Joomla K2 tags don't work with SEF

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, tags, sef, seo

I created a multilingual web site(blog) and everything worked fine, except filtering by tag.

My web site is on Joomla 3.4.3 and I am storing content using K2 ver. 2.6.9.

My articles have tags and when I tap on tag (filter articles by tag) I'm getting a 404 error page. Filtering by tag crashes when I use SEF, if I turn off SEF - everything works properly. Any ideas how to solve the problem? What could be the source of the problem: Joomla or K2 or maybe the template?

Here is [my blog and example of 404 page](http://iman007.com/en/tag/Android.html) (SEF is turned on) If SEF is off then my filter by tag "Android" [looks like this](http://iman007.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=tag&tag=Android&Itemid=101&lang=en).

Problem is the same on Joomla 3.4.4 (I have local copy of the web site). I tried to switch off web pages suffix but it didn't solve the problem.

I don't use 3rd party applications for SEF and content. SEF is core Joomla option. Also there are advanced SEF options in K2. Joomla and K2 forums haven't helped to fix issue.

P.S: turn off SEF is not a solution.

Comment: Additional info: tag filtering works when I turn off language filter, but it is not a solution, as my web site is multilingual. Url with SEF and lang filter looks like this: /en/tag/Android.html. Url without lang filter looks like this: /tag/Android.html

Comment: Andrew, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 1):

I have read that going to the language extension and re-saving the default language can solve some issues.

Also this Github discussion on the the Language Filter may be related to what you are experiencing. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/4215

And lastly this guide on multi-lingual site setup may be worth your time as well http://multilingual.demojoomla.com/multi-lingual-steps-by-steps.html

Hopefully one of these steps may sort your issue, or at least point you to a solution.